# How would you enter this approach with a racetrack course reversal at EGPH from the southwest?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts, approach

For reference this is the NDB ILS DME RWY 24 approach at EGPH. When arriving from the south/southwest, I am sure you would be vectored in but i am interested as to how this would be done without vectors. Assuming you are not coming from TLA, this would mean you cannot use the DME arc so your inital approach fix would be EDN, requiring a course reversal on the racetrack.

A few points:

- What is the smaller racetrack inside the larger one?
- I am assuming this would require a parallel entry? If so, how long would you travel along the inbound section before turning back around?
- Could you descend and intercept the glideslope after completing the racetrack/hold entry or would you have to do the entry, get back to EDN, then go back around the main racetrack to the top of the glideslope?

[image: RWY24 ILS EGPH]

Comment: A hold is a hold. A racetrack is a racetrack.

Comment: Hmm. Pressed Enter too early! And I don't know how to format it... 

A hold is a hold (but it does have a racetrack 'shape'!). A racetrack is a racetrack.
Note Racetracks are in bold. Holds are in normal (non-bold).
A hold is used as a delay.
A Racetrack is used to put you in a position where you can join the final approach course.

Comment: Hahaha I thought you were being snarky for a minute there! Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A caveat in that I haven't experienced the world of EASA, but this is how I see it through international convention:

> What is the smaller racetrack inside the larger one?

This is just the normal holding pattern, albeit with left hand turns.

> I am assuming this would require a parallel entry? If so, how long would you travel along the inbound section before turning back around?

Yes, and because it isn't otherwise specified, I would fly 1 minute legs.

> Could you descend and intercept the glideslope after completing the racetrack/hold entry or would you have to do the entry, get back to EDN, then go back around the main racetrack to the top of the glideslope?

No. The minimum altitude in the hold is 3000ft, and after 1 minute the glideslope would still be well beneath you.

When you are ready to commence the approach, you simply exit the hold via an extension of the outbound leg, on a track of 061. You must maintain this track and altitude until 12DME. From there you can turn left and intercept the localiser, remaining at 3000 until you have the glideslope (which can be expected at 9DME, which is also the FAF).

Comment: Thank you, that confirms my suspicions! Follow up: Would an FMS be capable of flying this automatically or would this need to be dialled in manually?

Answer (score 2):

The IAF is EDN, So, from the southwest I would approach the NDB, cross it, do a teardrop entry to the hold, cross the beacon again and start my procedural left turn.

When complete I would be on an outbound track of 061 degrees at which point I would report beacon outbound (if that was the instruction given - it iusually is). From there the procedure is fairly straightforward. Proceed out to 12DME and start left procedural turn to final track. Descend from 9DME with the glideslope.

---

There are not 2 racetracks. There is one standard hold which just so happens to be completely aligned with the outbound and inbound track.

---

I dont think this does require parallel entry, from the southwest I think you would be absolutely fine to do a teardrop entry as described above.

---

I dont quite follow your third question - but lets just say, in the real world, just ask for vectors to ILS :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific STAR that approaches you from south/south west and you are eager to apply this procedure, look at the plan view, chart does not say it is mandatory to approach from TLA side but it starts at over lctr at 3000'.

You follow your southern arrival procedure (star) descent 3000' and go over lctr, make parallel entry for the holding path and wait for your turn to approach. Get the 'clear ILS NDB aprooach for rwy 24'.Do approach checklist before you leave the holding. Fly outbound for 12nm turn for inbound do not descent until 9nm at which you will catch glide slope. Clear to land rwy 24!!

Comment: You are right that would be parallel !